# Data on Trading Activity in Fixed Income Markets

Tags: trading, fixed, income

Do any readers know of a good data source for trading volumes for fixed income assets (corporates [by rating, if possible], Treasuries, MBS and ABS) that provides historical data (back to 2008)? FINRA provides data from 2017 forward, but I require data from previous years as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at what frequency you wish for the trading statistics to be quoted but SIFMA [SIFMA Research Statistics](https://www.sifma.org/resources/archive/research/statistics/) has data going back to 2012 on an annual basis (including corporates by Rating). They do report the source of the data being FINRA TRACE.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful links.